# How can I elongate the content of table to be justified in the whole page in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I am trying to use the `exam` class for preparation of a question paper. At the top of first page, there is a necessity to provide the time, date and max marks. For this, I have created a `tabular` section while centering it as shown in the MWE below.

However, I would like the line to be spread throughout the page with even spacing between the columns. How can I achieve this?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \Large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}
    \end{center}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
            \textbf{Time: 3 Hours} & \textbf{Date: 07.12.2019} & \textbf{Max. Marks: 100}
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please refer the edited version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \Large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}
    \end{center}

\textbf{Time: 3 Hours} \hfill \textbf{Date: 07.12.2019} \hfill \textbf{Max. Marks: 100}\\

\hrule % or \hrulefill if necessary.
\end{document}
```

I don't think using tabular is necessary for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think a `\noindent` is needed at the beginning, but most important, this way the three columns do not have the same width, try with `\textbf{Time: 3 Hours} \hfill \textbf{Date: 07.12.2019} \hfill \textbf{Max. }` to see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In that case `tabularx` is better.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `tabular*` and `\extracolsep` (no packages).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \Large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}
    \end{center}
\begin{center}
        \tabcolsep=0pt% visably affects spacing on far right edge
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c }
            \textbf{Time: 3 Hours} & \textbf{Date: 07.12.2019} & \textbf{Max. Marks: 100}
        \end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a `tabularx` (this way the three columns have the same width):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \Large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \large \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}\\
        \textbf{XXX}
    \end{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X>{\centering}X>{\raggedleft}X}
            \textbf{Time: 3 Hours} & \textbf{Date: 07.12.2019} & \textbf{Max. Marks: 100}
        \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want the middle part to be centered below the main header: it's sufficient to make the right and left part zero width.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example


\begin{document}
\begin{center}\bfseries
\Large
XXX

\large
XXX\\
XXX\\
XXX

\normalsize

\bigskip

\makebox[0pt][l]{Time: 3 Hours}\hfill
Date: 07.12.2019\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{Max. Marks: 100}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is only used to show the text block margins.

[image]